# Are include parameters automatically passed to child includes?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Been working on a pretty complex Jekyll project, and I was having a really difficult time understanding how inheritance worked for included parameters. Structure is something like this:

File I'm working on:
`{% include test.html param='foo' %}`

test.html:

`TEST {{ include.param }}
{% include test2.html %}
{% include test3.html param2='woo' %}`

test2.html:
`TEST 2 {{ include.param }}`

test3.html:
`TEST 3 {{ include.param }} {{ include.param2 }}`

Output is: `TEST foo TEST 2 foo TEST 3 woo`

Sometimes `{{ include.param }}` is printed and sometimes it isn't. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

If you add an include with no parameters into a template, it'll inherit all the parameters of its parent.

However, if you add a single parameter to the child include, even if it's different than the one you're trying to call, then the include variables are reset for subsequent children.

You can still pass params in that case, doing something like this:

`{% include test3.html param=include.param param2='woo' %}`